# How to safely create file in bash

Tags: shell-script, mktemp

I have a script that creates a temporary file as a flag to guard against the script being run simultaneously. Currently it uses `tempfile`, e.g.

```bsh
if ! tempfile -n /tmp/updating > /dev/null; then
    echo 'Another synchronization is currently running' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The `tempfile` program is now deprecated, it suggests using `mktemp` instead, but `mktemp` doesn't seem to have an option similar to `-n`.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04.

So how should I safely create a flag file?

Comment: If you want to do this specifically with flag files, is `touch` an option?

Comment: What is the `-n` option supposed to do? I've never heard of `tempfile` before and have been using `mktemp` for many years. It seems, from an old man page I found online, that `-n` just gives a specific name for the "temp" file which seems very odd: if you already know the name, why would you need `tempfile` to create it? Why not just make your own lockfile name like `/tmp/thisisalongfilenamethatonlymyprogramnamedbestprogramwoulduse`?

Comment: Also - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045

Comment: @terdon "if you already know the name, bla bla" because you want to open it with `O_EXCL`? How can you do that from the shell?

Comment: Someone suggested flock in a comment, then deleted it. But it works for me.

Comment: @UncleBilly sorry, my ignorance requires more information. I'm afraid I don't even know what `O_EXCL` is. My point is that if you don't need a tool like `mktemp` that will create a unique, random name and instead you already know the name you'll be using, all you need is `if [[ -e $file ]]`.

Comment: @terdon - it's to avoid the race condition between checking that the file doesn't exist and creating it. It's probably over-engineering for my purpose, but I think it's good practice.

Comment: @inian - that's a good resource. I'm (now) using the "flock file descriptor uniqueness" version as described in the flock man page.

Comment: @Peregrino69 - I don't understand how I would use `touch` for this. Could you please explain further?

Comment: @StevePiner - since you've resolved your issue, please don't hesitate to [answer it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. You might need to wait for a time before you can accept it, but it's a good practice as it'll mark your question as containing solution for others down the line, and lift it off the Unanaswered -queue. Please do describe also how you're using flock.

Comment: @StevePiner Basically I was suggesting similar approach to terdon's, creating your own lock file with a chosen name. It's what I usually do and my script's behavior depends on the existence of the file. But as you've resolved this, it's a bit of a moot point :-)

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested flock in a comment, then deleted it. While using flock doesn't exactly answer the question as asked (the file is not safely created), it is sufficient for my need (as the lock does prevent the critical section of the script from being run several times simultaneously)

The code above has been changed as follows: it now opens a file descriptor to the `/tmp/updating` file then locks the open file descriptor.

```bsh
exec 4<>/tmp/updating
if ! flock --nonblock --exclusive 4; then
    echo 'Another synchronization is currently running' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

At the end of the script to release the lock was a `rm /tmp/updating`. I no longer need to do that as the flock will automatically be released when the script exits.

The man page for [flock(1)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/flock.1.html) has some examples for use in different scenarios, I've used the last one.

Comment: Using non-unique filenames in `/tmp` is considered very unsafe in the multi-user environment.

Comment: I would suggest using `flock(1)` on the script file itself. Unfortunately flock is not portable.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - good to know. I've moved it elsewhere

Comment: @UncleBilly - nice idea! Re: flock portability, fortunately I don't need it to be portable.